# Oracle Report Server does not refresh keymap (cgicmd.dat)

Tags: oraclereports

We are using Oracle Report Server 11.1.1.2 and the simple thing that we are trying to do is to disable some report keys whose reports are now decommissioned. So we just placed a ';' before the desired rep.keys ( cgicmd.dat ) and restarted the server. That would have been too simple!

By no means until now we have managed to disable those reports:

- changed rwservlet.properties adding < reloadkeymap >yes< /reloadkeymap >
- checking cgicmd.dat format ( space in the end of each line,... )
- copying those two files from the configuration directory to where the deployed internal reports application is located.
- restarted webcache( even kept it shutdown )
- a couple of more try/error desperate solutions!

Any hint rather then shutting of the server, for now, is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

All those previous attempts were followed by application server restarts at the Enterprise Manager console ( both in-process server and standalone ).

However, it seems that an higher level of restart was needed, because when we restarted the Reports J2EE Application in the Weblogic Administration Console, everything was synchronized!

I guess that having < reloadkeymap >yes< /reloadkeymap > was an important detail, anyway!